# search bar change the y value after search something

Tags: uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, ios7.1

I have a added search controller to search locations from google. My problem is after type something is search bar, its going to change the position of the search bar. I have added the screen shots. Please give me a solution for this

Befor type anything[image]

when typing something on searchbar

[image]

After click on the one location

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On PC it's quite common for people from some countries like Poland, because there are two different languages for the keyboard: Polish (214) and Polish (programmers).
The first one has got a totally different layout and switches Y & Z with places (and many keys also). Polish (programmers) is the same as English. It could be fixed by pressing Alt+Shift buttons. Every press changes language from your keyboards lists. I guess there are different keyboard layouts for different languages on Android, so just go to keyboard settings and delete the ones you're not using, or simply select the one you need (English I guess).

Comment: My problem is not about the keyboard,, the searchbar is changing the position when I start to type something

Comment: Y and Z is not a coincidence, so it's a bug in the software or application is using different keyboard set, or it schuffles keyboard sets when you start to type. I would go to the android settings and disable all keyboard layouts except english.